# Cypress FX3 CyU3PToolChainInit Understanding help

Tags: microcontroller, c, arm, firmware, c++

I don't understand the purpose of the CyU3PToolChainInit function that is written in assembly source code for the FXE. As for as I know it clears the BSS area and enters the main function, but how is this function generated? What is a tool chain? I mean I understand it's everything from a compiler to a link but what initialize it in a micro controller?

[SDK API Manual](http://www.cypress.com/system/files/document/files/FX3APIGuide_0.pdf)

[Programmer's Manual](http://www.cypress.com/file/124386/download)

Comment: The FX3 SDK includes a version of this function for the GNU ARM tool-chain. This implementation only clears the
BSS segment and then jumps to the main function.
If the user application requires a heap (uses malloc / new), it should be initialized in this function.

Comment: Thanks but I've seen that already

Comment: Why not just clear the BSS area in C/C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done deeper research into the matter and have concluded that the CyU3PToolChainInit is a pre-written function by Cypress and the BSS area is cleared in assembly before initializing the full OS simply for efficiency. Moreover, memory heap is set in this function prior to RTOS initialization in order to prevent the OS using memory that may otherwise be required.